# Create Android APK

Tags: javascript, html, apk, phpstorm

I just created a nice little memory game with HTML and Javascript in Phpstorm.
But I would like it to get my game as a APK so I can submit it to Google Play. And I aslo don't know anything about APK's
Could some tell me how I can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Android documentation rocks. Good luck. http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create the APK for your little game. 
Firstly you should have some basic knowledge of Android. Load your URL inside a webview(take care of loading the page and stuff like that) and create the APK. 
Now, you are readywith your app to be loaded into the Play Store.